# Prove that $\det( M) \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, determinant

> Let $\Gamma$ be a finite multiplicative group of matrices with complex entries. Let $M$ denote the sum of the matrices in $\Gamma$. Prove that det $M$ is an integer. 
>  **Hint:** square $M$ and use the distributivity of multiplication with respect to the sum of matrices.

---

I tried using the hint but I am not able to get to anything.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let $G_1,G_2, \dots, G_k$ be the elements of $\Gamma$.

$$M^2 = (G_1+G_2+ \dots+ G_k)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}G_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^k G_j\right)$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^{k}G_i \left(\sum_{G \in \Gamma} G_i^{-1}G\right) = \sum_{G \in \Gamma} \sum_{i=1}^{k}G_i(G_i^{-1}G) = k\sum_{G \in \Gamma}G = kM$$
Taking determinants, we get that $(\det M)^2 = k^n \det M$. Hence either $\det M = 0$ or $\det M$ is equal to the order of $\Gamma$ raised to the $n$th power.

Answer (score 16):

This can also be proved using basic representation theory of finite groups (this may be an overkill, though).

A group $\Gamma$ of $N\times N$ matrices can be seen as an abstract group equiped with a representation on a N-dimensional complex vector space. $\frac{M}{|\Gamma|}$ is well-known to be the projection onto the subspace of invariants. Now, concider two cases:

- The whole vector space is invariant. Thus, the subspace of invariants coincides with the whole space, and the projection operator coincides with the identity: $\frac{M}{|\Gamma|} = 1$. Taking determinants, we have $\frac{\det M}{|\Gamma|^N}=1$, or $\det M = |\Gamma|^N$. Note that in this case all matrices from the group act as identity operators (since the whole space consists of invariants), thus they *are* identity operators, and the group is actually trivial: $|\Gamma|=1$ and $\det M=1$.
- The subspace of invariants is proper. Then, the projection operator has a nontrivial kernel and is not injective, so $\det\frac{M}{|\Gamma|}=0$ and $\det M=0$.

Thus, we have only two options:

- $\Gamma$ is trivial and $\det M=1$
- $\Gamma$ is *not* trivial and $\det M=0$

Note that in any case $\det M \in \{0,1\}$, not just $\det M \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Overkill is good, since it maybe gives more insight than clever tricks.

Comment: It's worth stressing more that if $|\Gamma|>1$, the determinant of the sum is necessarily zero, and that always $\det(M)\in\{0,1\}$ (which is much more than the claim $\det(M)\in\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta This sounds reasonable, thank you. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Hint:

Let $\Gamma=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$.

Note $$M^2 = \sum_{i,j} A_i A_j = n \sum_i A_i = n M.$$
(For fixed $i$, $\Gamma=\{A_iA_1,A_iA_2,\ldots,A_iA_n\}$, so the double sum goes over all elements, each $n$ times.)